# Sever level MongoDB authentication

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to put authentication on mongodb, which I already did, but the thing is that the authentication is at Database level not at Server level. e.g. A person can connect to my mongo server without authentication, he/she can do a random guess about the DB name and `use DBName` will show the Databse but not the collection and documents inside it. My prime agenda is to restrict access to my server without proper credentials altogetger. I tried official mongo document but it is quite vague. Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: You can block the access to the MongoDB port in the firewall and only allow IPs you trust. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-network/

Comment: @megas Yes, I restart the server by using following command `mongod --auth --config="config file path"`.

Comment: @Jan Yes, I have tried limiting the access to selective IPs but the IPs are dynamic and can change at any point of time. So I am trying to block the access to server itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that authentication cannot be applied at server level because mongodb does not have web server as we have in MSSQL or MySQL. So, we can only apply auth at DB level and restrict visibility of our server by VNet and by configuring firewall.